# SQL - How to Delete master data with many relation and used in many time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

What is the best practice to delete a column that be used a lot in system (I use SQL Server and EF6 code first)

For example:

I have a table to store the department information. In some business, they use a lot of this department information in many business, and there are some stored procedures used it too. In some case, this department will be removed but I am not sure what is the best way.

In my thought, I have 2 solution :

Solution #1:

Add a column named `IsDeleted` and set it true/false, but it will not take effect with the existing stored procedure.

Solution #2:

Add a table named `Recycle`, I will store the Id and the type of the object that been deleted. And create a view to call it on system.

Any other solution? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to store your deleted data you can also: provide another table and trigger your main table for delete to do insert data into your backing table when data get deleted in main table

Comment: hi Farheg, I like your idea, the data in real was not deleted, and I can do a recovery function.  Thanks you

Comment: you are welcome, there are also many other solution for it some depends on your RDBMS.  but the thing I mentioned is also good. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best practice in your case is to use the idea of soft-delete, less expensive, and here some links that I hope it will help you

1. [Soft delete with Entity Framework](https://emerbrito.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/soft-delete-with-entity-framework/)
2. [Entity Framework: Soft Deletes Are Easy](https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/)
3. [Soft Delete pattern for Entity Framework Code First](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html)